# jQuery to extract html from href link

Tags: jquery, cheerio

This Meteor server side uses Cheerio in order to extract 98771 from

```
<li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98771" title="Postcode 98771, California">98771</a>
```

which happened to be link number 33 in the array `postcodesLinks`.

I just want to get a list of all the post codes on the page so that I can save them to a mongodb collection.

```
let $ = cheerio.load(response.content);
let postcodeLinks = $('a[title^=Postcode]');
console.log(postcodeLinks.length); // <----- this works fine
console.log(postcodeLinks[33].html()); // <----- this fails
console.log(postcodeLinks[33].text()); // <----- this fails
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a 33rd element on the page when you run your code? Also, are you wrapping this in a "ready" `$(function() { ... });` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Cheerio is based off of jQuery, so I will use Cheerio/jQuery interchangeable in this answer since the core concepts are the same...</sub>

---

When you use a jQuery selector like `$('a[title^=Postcode]')`, a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) is returned, which is essentially an array-like collection of [DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

You are accessing one of the elements in the collection by its index with `postcodeLinks[33]`, which means that you are attempting to use the jQuery methods `.html()` and `.text()` on a native DOM element. Since jQuery methods aren't implemented on native HTML elements, it does not work.

Therefore you need to use the `.html()`/`.text()` methods on a jQuery object.

One option is to use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) (which is implemented in both jQuery and Cheerio). In doing so, the `.eq()` method will access an element by its index and return a jQuery object:

```
postcodeLinks.eq(33).html()
// or..
postcodeLinks.eq(33).text()
```

Alternatively, you could also wrap the DOM element with `$()` in order to convert it back to a jQuery object:

```
$(postcodeLinks[33]).html()
// or..
$(postcodeLinks[33]).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.html()` expects to get like a jQuery object so you need to: wrap `postcodeLinks[33]` into `$()` like:

```
$(postcodeLinks[33]).html()
```

```js
let postcodeLinks = $('a[title^=Postcode]');
console.log(postcodeLinks.length); // <----- this works fine
console.log($(postcodeLinks[33]).html()); // <----- this works fine
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98771" title="Postcode 98771, California">98771</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98772" title="Postcode 98772, California">98772</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98773" title="Postcode 98773, California">98773</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98774" title="Postcode 98774, California">98774</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98775" title="Postcode 98775, California">98775</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98776" title="Postcode 98776, California">98776</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98777" title="Postcode 98777, California">98777</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98778" title="Postcode 98778, California">98778</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98779" title="Postcode 98779, California">98779</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98780" title="Postcode 98780, California">98780</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98781" title="Postcode 98781, California">98781</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98782" title="Postcode 98782, California">98782</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98783" title="Postcode 98783, California">98783</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98784" title="Postcode 98784, California">98784</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98785" title="Postcode 98785, California">98785</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98786" title="Postcode 98786, California">98786</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98787" title="Postcode 98787, California">98787</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98788" title="Postcode 98788, California">98788</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98789" title="Postcode 98789, California">98789</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98790" title="Postcode 98790, California">98790</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98791" title="Postcode 98791, California">98791</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98792" title="Postcode 98792, California">98792</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98793" title="Postcode 98793, California">98793</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98794" title="Postcode 98794, California">98794</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98795" title="Postcode 98795, California">98795</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98796" title="Postcode 98796, California">98796</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98797" title="Postcode 98797, California">98797</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98798" title="Postcode 98798, California">98798</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98799" title="Postcode 98799, California">98799</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98800" title="Postcode 98800, California">98800</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98801" title="Postcode 98801, California">98801</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98802" title="Postcode 98802, California">98802</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98803" title="Postcode 98803, California">98803</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98804" title="Postcode 98804, California">98804</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98805" title="Postcode 98805, California">98805</a></li>
</ul>
```

Doing the same without jQuery looks more like you expected:

```js
let postcodeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[title^=Postcode]');
console.log(postcodeLinks.length); // <----- this works fine
console.log(postcodeLinks[33].innerHTML); // <----- this works fine
```

```html
<ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98771" title="Postcode 98771, California">98771</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98772" title="Postcode 98772, California">98772</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98773" title="Postcode 98773, California">98773</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98774" title="Postcode 98774, California">98774</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98775" title="Postcode 98775, California">98775</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98776" title="Postcode 98776, California">98776</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98777" title="Postcode 98777, California">98777</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98778" title="Postcode 98778, California">98778</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98779" title="Postcode 98779, California">98779</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98780" title="Postcode 98780, California">98780</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98781" title="Postcode 98781, California">98781</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98782" title="Postcode 98782, California">98782</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98783" title="Postcode 98783, California">98783</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98784" title="Postcode 98784, California">98784</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98785" title="Postcode 98785, California">98785</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98786" title="Postcode 98786, California">98786</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98787" title="Postcode 98787, California">98787</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98788" title="Postcode 98788, California">98788</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98789" title="Postcode 98789, California">98789</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98790" title="Postcode 98790, California">98790</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98791" title="Postcode 98791, California">98791</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98792" title="Postcode 98792, California">98792</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98793" title="Postcode 98793, California">98793</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98794" title="Postcode 98794, California">98794</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98795" title="Postcode 98795, California">98795</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98796" title="Postcode 98796, California">98796</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98797" title="Postcode 98797, California">98797</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98798" title="Postcode 98798, California">98798</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98799" title="Postcode 98799, California">98799</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98800" title="Postcode 98800, California">98800</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98801" title="Postcode 98801, California">98801</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98802" title="Postcode 98802, California">98802</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98803" title="Postcode 98803, California">98803</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98804" title="Postcode 98804, California">98804</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.postcodes-california.com/postcodes/98805" title="Postcode 98805, California">98805</a></li>
  </ul>
```